# vim: how to respect quoted string on gq?

Tags: vim

Using default gq behaviour, vim always split on space. I want another behaviour based on quoted string. eg.

```
'foo', 'bar', 'foo bar', 'fff', 'bar foo'
```

by default split to

```
'foo', 'bar', 'foo 
bar', 'fff', 'bar foo'
```

I want it to be

```
'foo', 'bar', 
'foo bar', 'fff',
'bar foo'
```

is it possible?

Comment: Not via something built into Vim, but you can implement a custom `'formatexpr'`.

Comment: You can do this with a macro, in this case `2f,lr<enter>+` and then `2@a`

Comment: @TheChetan the string just example, I have a lot of string in my code

Comment: A macro based solution will scale, you just have to make sure of using the correct macro.